# async/await return value from function for array map

Tags: javascript

Having trouble figuring out how to get this below code to work in javascript/react;

```
findSupplierName(supplierId) {
   var object = this.state.supplierData.find(e => e.id === supplierId).name;
   return object;
}
```

I have two API calls returning arrays, one contains orders while the other contains supplier information. I'm trying to find the supplier_id from the order array into a name from the supplier array.

```
<tbody>
   {this.state.data.map((data, i) =>
   <tr key={i}>
     <td>{data.id}</td>
     <td>{this.findSupplierName(data.supplier_id)}</td>
     <td>{data.date}</td>
     <td>{data.total}</td>
   </tr>)}
</tbody>
```

I've tried using async/await but haven't been able to figure it out (Javascript newbie here). Most of the time the code fails as the find function takes a while to find the info.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason** JavaScript's map function works with an array, and initially `this.state.data` are undefined until it gets response from ajax request.

you must switch `async: false`. then the requested data will be recieved and the rest of the code will run right after the data is recieved.

Comment: The function that calls the api and stores the data into this.state.data is already using async and that isn't the problem, rather it's the findSupplierName function which needs to use async/await in order to wait for the result before returning it. Thats the part i can't figure out.